# python float division by zero when plotting treemap chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, treemap

I'm new to python matplotlib and trying to plot a treemap chart, thanks in advance!

```
squarify.plot(sizes=df['vvmins'], label=df['category_name'], alpha=.8)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

then the 'float division by zero' error show up, my data set is like below(dummy):
[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove the 0 in advance, because the treemap represents the composition ratio in one area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Either of these options should work:

1. Remove any 0 values in advance, as mentioned in the comments. For a Pandas dataframe, this can be accomplished by filtering for rows that do NOT have 0 values prior to plotting. (Currently commented out in code below). OR,
2. If you want to retain the label that had a value of 0, you could add a very small fraction to all of your sizes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import squarify
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"category_name": ["a", "c", "k", "s", "e", "d", "a", "d", "e", "s", "z", "k", "k", "k"],
     "vvmins": [4, 9, 2, 4, 5, 5, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7, 5, 2, 0],
    }
)
##### OPTION 1 #####
# Filter out rows with value of 0
# df = df.loc[df["vvmins"] != 0]

##### OPTION 2 #####
# Add a very small number to each element of size column
df["vvmins"] = df["vvmins"].apply(lambda x: x + 0.000001)

# Optional sorting of categories so like labels are together
# Pairs well with OPTION 1
# df.sort_values("category_name", inplace=True)

# Plot as before
squarify.plot(sizes=df["vvmins"], 
              label=df["category_name"], 
              alpha=0.8,
              pad=True # adds white space; 0-value label more visible
             )
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```